# QuickBlox Chat - Are messages stored?

Tags: quickblox

I have a doubt about QuickBlox. 
I want to use the chat functionality but I need to know if the messages exchanged between users are stored in database. because I need to retrieve them to show a list of the users I've talked to and the last message, such as facebook app in iOS and Android.

Thanks!

Comment: No, I would have to use Custom Classes or store in the device, which didn't satisfy my needs. I ended up creating my own backend with Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is info about chat history

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Manage_Chat_History

Comment: how to get this history in Android

Comment: A more direct link with examples for the plugin that does exactly this (taken from the link above): http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/1:1_Chat_history