# Quickblox 50 messages from room history

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

My question is base on [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743379/quickblox-chat-are-messages-stored/16758146)

I have also read [this](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Manage_Chat_History)

Where this is written

```
"By default, maximum number of history messages returned by room is 50. There is no way to change this value now."
```

now my question is that .Is this limit apply for every single user or 50 messages combining all users of room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get **last 50** messages of all users in current chatroom. In near future, Quickblox iOS SDK will provide API for control this feature. Please check last updates of framework at http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog:

Good luck!

Comment: Can we have image and video in rooms and if so will those be also included in the history?

Comment: you can add link to image or video in message. In this case it included in the history

Comment: OK. Thanks for the suggestion. How can we differentiate among image/video/text unless we send extra keys along with the message. According to me, adding some keys within the text and then extracting them using some regular expressions can be helpful. Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: No, I think. Anyway, you'll need parse message on receiver side in this case